# MediaPlayer или Фрагменты

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, mediaplayer

Добрый вечер господа. Учусь кодить под андроид, и в данный момент столкнулся вот с какого рода проблемой.

Фрагмент(`Fragment`) вызывается из другого фрагмента(`ListFragment`) на фрагменте 2 кнопки. Запускаем начинает играть интернет радио. Нажимаем паузу все останавливается. И все было бы хорошо если бы не одно но, когда сворачивается приложение или же мы покидаем фрагмент, музыка продолжает играть. Но после того как снова вернулись обратно (`ListFragment ---> Fragment`) по нажатию на паузу `MediaPlayer` уже не останавливается, а при нажатии `Play` запускается еще один звуковой поток.

Как вернуться именно в тот фрагмент из которого мы вызывали первую звуковую дорожку ? =_=

```
package com.slaanesh.mediaplayerexample;


import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RadioWaveFragment extends Fragment{
    private int id;
    private Button play,stop;
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        View view = getView();
        if (view!=null){

            play = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_play);
            stop = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mp.setDataSource(rw.getUrl());
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v("error","error");
            }

            play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {                        
                    mp.start();
                }
            });

            stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mp.pause();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_playradio, container, false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что каждый раз во фрагменте вы создаёте новый объект плеера, вместо использования уже существующего. Попробуйте создать класс, возвращающий всегда один и тот же объект для всего приложения (паттерн синглтон):

```
public class MyPlayer
{
    static MediaPlayer mp;

    public static MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer()
    {
        if (mp == null)
        {
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
        }

        return mp;
    }
}
```

После чего в коде пользоваться именно им:

```
//общий плеер на всё приложение
mp = MyPlayer.getMediaPlayer();
//вместо одного на 
//mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, видимо надо больше отдыхать. Пока пробовал на своем живом девайсе пришел к выводу метод start самый тяжеловесный , после нажатия кнопки Play 8-10 секунд задержка. Смотрел по логам методы типа reset,setDataSource,prepareAsync срабатывают сразу.
04-04 13:47:40.036 16027-16027/? V/MyLog: reset if not null
04-04 13:47:40.051 16027-16027/? V/MyLog: get URL
04-04 13:47:40.063 16027-16027/? V/MyLog: prepared 
04-04 13:47:48.856 16027-16027/? V/MyLog: satrted (8 секунд)

можно ли как то на это повлиять или это пора девайс менять ?

Comment: @AlexandrTumakov, измерений никогда не делал, так что не знаю нормально ли это. Попробуйте на разных девайсах/эмуляторах измерить.